# Restangular post

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I am trying to use restangular in my project, I have the set up and config all working fine.
I need to make a post request where i have the url and a json payload.

```
var url = xyz.com + "/api/v2/create?type=project";
eg payload
       '{
        "class":"Project",
        "name":"test_project",
        "description":"test_project",
        "owner":{"class":"User","id":"2"},
        "connection":{"class":"Connection","id":"1"},
        "defaultNamespace":"default",
        "namespaces":["default"]}'
```

I was unsure of how to make a restangular call, should the post have the payload as params?
I tried this below, but did not seem to work.

```
Restangular.all('create').post({
        "class":"Project",
        "name":"test_project",
        "description":"test_project",
        "owner":{"class":"User","id":"2"},
        "connection":{"class":"Connection","id":"1"},
        "defaultNamespace":"default",
        "namespaces":["default"]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you should do something like:

```
Restangular.all('create').post(
// First the object
{
  class: "Project",
  name: "Test-project",
  owner: {
    class: "User"
  }  
},
// Then the request params
{type: "Project"}
);
```

That should do it :)